# How can I combine several blocks of image in to one image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have divided an image into 32x32 blocks. Now I want to combine these blocks to recover the original image. How can I do this using matlab?

This is the code I use to divide the image in to blocks:

```
C=imread('lena.jpg');
C = rgb2gray(C);
C=imread('D1.gif')
x2=im2double(x1);

    [m,n,k]=size(x2) % and m=n with 1 channel k=1
    ImageSize=m*n;
    BlockD=32; 
    BlockSize=BlockD*BlockD;
    NoOfBlock=ImageSize/BlockSize;
    SubB=zeros(BlockD,BlockD,NoOfBlock); %arrays of blocks.
    X=zeros(BlockD,BlockD,NoOfBlock);
%    important to convert uint8 to double when dialing with image. 
%     thats what ru asking for.
    k=1;
    for i=1:BlockD:m
      for j=1:BlockD:n
        x(:,:,k)=x2(i:i+BlockD-1,j:j+BlockD-1);
        k=k+1;

      end
    end
```

Comment: Maybe [`imtile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imtile.html) helps

Comment: Have you tried reversing the assignment inside the loop?

Comment: how i reversing the assigment in the loop?

Comment: Write `x2(i:i+BlockD-1,j:j+BlockD-1) = x(:,:,k);`. You just need to create an empty `x2` of the right size before the loop.

Comment: Also, note that MATLAB is case sensitive. In your code you define `X`, but then assign into `x`. You should assign into `X` instead. It's legal to assign into a matrix that doesn't exist, or assign in a way that grows the array, but it is not at all efficient. Your code will be faster if you assign into `X` (or define `x` with the right size before the loop).

Comment: thank's for your help